# Disable square style on my editor PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

How do I remove these colored squares in my code? What are they for?

Thx!

[image]

Comment: 1) What theme that is? Is that Material Theme UI and it's some extra option from them? This can be theme specific or some glitch after changing the themes. 2) Will it go away in another file? 3) Will it disappear if you switch to one of the bundled themes? 4) In either case: right now, based on what I see on your limited screenshot, it shows no logic in why only some elements are highlighted this way. You would need to find some logic on "what this might be", then we can see what style/option to change.

Comment: @LazyOne Thx you ! That was the theme. I'm not familiar with PHPSTORM.. and there's so much stuff, I thought it was part of the IDE and not my installed theme. Thank you for your help!

Comment: After looking at your screenshot again... I think those square boxes may represent a Typo (Spellchecker). If that's the case then you should be able to alter your *Color Scheme* -- just use the search box in the Settings/Preferences screen, type `typo` and go through the results. That's my best guess right now based on the screenshot.